# Retrieving a property of a JSON object by another value?

Tags: angularjs, json

My Angular script is -

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
app.controller('myCtrl', function($scope) {

 $scope.set = [{"minValue":"30","ord":"414"}, {"minValue":"60","ord":"503"}, {"minValue":"90","ord":"541"}];

});
```

If I find min value like it is 60 then I want to find ordinal(ord) for that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use javascript `find` prototype function to find and return object from array

```
 $scope.minVal = "60"
 $scope.set = [{"minValue":"30","ord":"414"}, {"minValue":"60","ord":"503"}, {"minValue":"90","ord":"541"}];

 $scope.obj = $scope.set.find(o => o.minValue === $scope.minVal);

 console.log( $scope.obj.ord )
```

Demo

```js
angular.module("app",[])
.controller("ctrl",function($scope){
 $scope.minVal = "60"
 $scope.set = [{"minValue":"30","ord":"414"}, {"minValue":"60","ord":"503"}, {"minValue":"90","ord":"541"}];
 
 $scope.obj = $scope.set.find(o => o.minValue === $scope.minVal);
 
 console.log( $scope.obj.ord )
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="app" ng-controller="ctrl">
 
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Depends upon where do you want that i.e.

1) if you only want to filter that for your controller logic and then to use that value as a separate variable/scope variable then You can simply use javascript `find` function

```
//Say simply you have target 'minValue' in a variable
$scope.searchValue = '60';
var result = $scope.set.find(function(v){return v.minValue == $scope.searchValue});
//it will return the array of all data with 'minValue == 60 ' in your case

//So in your case the actual value you want would be 
console.log(result.ord);
```

2) If you just want to filter the ng-repeat in html then you can use 'filter'

```
<div ng-repeat="item in set | filter : {'minValue': searchValue}">
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use [filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) method which is available in ES5

```js
angular.module("app", [])
  .controller("ctrl", function($scope) {
    $scope.minVal = "60"
    $scope.set = [{
      "minValue": "30",
      "ord": "414"
    }, {
      "minValue": "60",
      "ord": "503"
    }, {
      "minValue": "90",
      "ord": "541"
    }];

    $scope.obj = $scope.set.filter(function(val) {
      return val.minValue === $scope.minVal;
    });

    console.log($scope.obj)
  })
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="app" ng-controller="ctrl">

</div>
```